# Bootstrap 5 accordion not working in a table cell

Tags: bootstrap-5, accordion

Bootstrap accordion functionality inside the bootstrap table cell is not working while working fine once I pull out the code from table , Can someone please have a look and let me know what i am doing wrong here.

Attaching the code as below .

```html
<div  class="container-fluid">
        <form method="post">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">col1</th>
                            <th scope="col">col2</th>
                            <th scope="col">col3</th>
                            <th scope="col">col4</th>
                            <th scope="col">col5</th>
                            <th scope="col">col6</th>
                            <th scope="col">col7</th>
                            <th scope="col">col8</th>
                            <th scope="col">col9</th>
                            <th scope="col">col10</th>
                            <th scope="col">col11</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    {% for lstelm in setup_all_config %}
                    <tr>
                        {% for elm in lstelm %}
                        {% if loop.index == 1 %}
                        <td>
                            <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
                                <div class="accordion-item">
                                  <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                                    <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                      Item #1
                                    </button>
                                  </h2>
                                  <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                                    <div class="accordion-body">
                                    first
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                        </td>
                        {% elif loop.index == 11 %}
                        <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-success">{{elm}}</a></td>
                        {% else %}
                        <td>{{elm}}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}

                </table>
           
            </br>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.table tr th:last-child{
        width: 50%;
    }
    .table tr th,.table tr td {
      border:1px solid #ddd
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td><div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  Accordion Item #1
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Accordion Item #2
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                  Accordion Item #3
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .table tr th:last-child{
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>


<table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td><div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                  Accordion Item #1
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                  Accordion Item #2
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-item">
              <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
                <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                  Accordion Item #3
                </button>
              </h2>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                  <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit overflow.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).